# firebase deploy gives error in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

**Output On Terminal**

!  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions.
Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.

=== Deploying to 'fir-90846'...

i  deploying storage, firestore, functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build E:\Flutter Projects\agent_softezi\functions
> tsc

- functions: Finished running predeploy script.

There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.

Error: Server Error. write EPROTO 11640:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read this before posting, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We need your comamnd, what have you typed / tried out? describe a bit your environment. Form a question. Do not just drop an error log.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your firebase-functions version is updated, to update your version execute the command below in your flutter function directory `/flutter_project_name/functions`:

```
npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
```

For function deploying error with the message about App engine, I saw a similar issues that running the command below should fix the problem:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

If still not resolved as the error message said and suggest to open a ticket with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).